# How to codesign a PyInstaller + PyQt app on Mac OSX avoiding "binary is not signed" errors after notarizing the app?

Tags: macos, pyqt5, pyinstaller, code-signing

I have followed various PyInstaller recipes to code sign my Mac OSX PyQt5-based app , including:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing-Qt

I can build the app, codesign it with my developer ID certificate, and verify it without problem. But, when I send the app for notarizing, it gets rejected with all the libraries copied over to Resources (following the recipe above) being reported as "the binary is not signed" and "The signature does not include a secure timestamp", for example:

```
Contents/Resources/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtQuickControls2.framework/Versions/5/QtQuickControls2"
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for dealing with this problem?

Comment: did you ever get this issue resolved. I'm facing exactly the same problem. Do all of your errors refer to directories with periods in the name? I'm wondering if that might be a problem.

Comment: I did get it solved! Using the latest Pyinstaller basically fixes all the weird issues. If you have directories with periods in the name, you need to run a script to address the problem, which is also on the Pyinstaller site. Check the post for building apps for distribution on Mac OS.

Comment: Is this the script fix_app_qt_folder_names_for_codesign.py ? I did run it and was told 7 file names were fixed. Interestingly, I still see within PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQml/ folder names with periods. This is true for both the MacOS and Resources directories. Does that mean the script did not do what I wanted? I did codesign and used codesign --verify --verbose to receive the message "satisfies its Designated Requirement" However notarization still failed. The only way to remove the notarization error messages was to delete all folder names and codesign again. I'm still missing something.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late reply. I didn't use QML so I didn't have this issue. But, I was using the Web components of QT, which also seems to introduce .qml files. The only way to get past notarization was to codesign each file that generated an error separately:

Comment: Thanks so much for the update!